# Insert a page break within a div when printing, after n number of dynamically generated text boxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Similar questions have been asked, but I haven't yet found anything that solves my specific problem.
I have an empty div:

```
<div id="data"> </div>
```

into which dynamically generated text boxes are appended using javascript. The div's css is:

```
#data{width:230px; height:auto; left:0px; top:60px; position:relative;}
```

And the text boxes css is (javascript gives them the class "tagN"):

```
.tagN{background:url('text.gif'); display:inline; position:relative; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px;}
```

So far everything works fine. The only problem is this: the text boxes can sometimes be more than 50 and as they occupy one print line each, when the page is printed (or print-previewed) both in IE and Firefox, four lines are missing right between the pages.
I have thought of inserting a white block after every 50 text boxes in the following (text box generating script):

```
    function addText(spa1, spa2, fcss, count){
    $('<input type="text">').attr({'id':'d' + progress, 'name':'d' + progress}).data("raw", rawVal).val(toInch(spa1 + count * spa2))
        .css("font-weight", fcss).prop('readonly', true).addClass("tagN").appendTo(data);
}
```

Is there another way to tell the browser to "not print" into the bottom margin of the page? I am looking for a javascript solution preferably.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use following css property to split to pages

> page-break-after:always;

Or if you dont want to split at all inside an element add following style

> page-break-inside: avoid;

Answer (score 0):

Easy and simple solution is to set `page-break-after` css property to each textbox so that while printing page it will appear on separate page.

Refer this
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_print_pageba.asp

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved it! Here's how:
First, I figured out that I want 40 lines on a single page. Each line takes up 16px, because my dynamically-generated text boxes have a css height:16px.
Then I made my header, consisting of images etc. on the first page 4 lines long = 64px.
So, starting from 4, I created a variable

```
var pageCounter = 4;
```

Then, each time a text box is dynamically generated, I added the following to the function:

```
pageCounter++; //adds 1
var div40 = pageCounter / 40;
if(div40==Math.floor(pageCounter / 40)){ //if var div40 has reached 40 lines
  $('<input type="text">').attr({'id':'p'+pageCounter, 'name':'p'+pageCounter})
  // create a text box with a unique id and name
  .val("continued on next page...") // value to show on the print sheet
  .prop('readonly', true).addClass("pBreak").appendTo(data);
  // append to main div
```

These text boxes should not show on screen, so I added to the css of the pBreak class:

```
.pBreak{display:none;}
```

Then, at print time I want them to show, so:

```
    @media print{
      .pBreak{display:inline; page-break-after:always;
    }
```

That displays text boxes with "continued on next page..." every 40 lines and also page-breaks at the same spots.

If there is a simpler way to do the above, I would welcome your input - thanks!